# How to get image from response and save it in models.ImageField

Tags: python, django, image-processing

Asking this I realize that topic is quite common and perhaps was discussed many times. But it still not clear for me, so I'm trying to get image file from response, resize it and save it in model. I deal with the error:

> AttributeError at /saveimage/
>   'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'

my code is like so:

```
import Image
import cStringIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
def get_and_save_image():
    file = cStringIO.StringIO()
    size = (200,200)
    color = (255,0,0,0)
    image = Image.new("RGBA", size, color)
    image.save(file, format='JPEG')
    image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file, None, 'foo.jpg', 'jpeg', None, None)
    image_file.seek(0)
    return image_file
```

Http response:

```
FILES:
some_image = <InMemoryUploadedFile: image.jpg (image/jpeg)>
```

Is it the proper way to save image into ImageField? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using a form with imagefield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield? It should handle everything for you instead of you manually creating stuff.

Comment: I select image with enctype="multipart/form-data” in my template , then send it via Query.ajaxForm(http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and trying to get it from response.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can do this:

1. Save the image in a models.ImageField, and then return the image's url in the response, and you can create the image element in javascript and add the url.
2. Encode the image's data in base64 and return it as a string, which you can easily use in the front end. Here's an example of this:

Backend:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
def get_and_save_image():
    size = (200,200)
    color = (255,0,0,0)
    image = Image.new("RGBA", size, color)
    img_buffer = BytesIO()
    image.save(img_buffer, format='JPEG')
    response_string = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue())
    return response_string
```

Front end:

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ THE_RESPONSE_STRING }}">`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply but If I run your code if fails with error AttributeError at /saveimage/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
and traceback:
**Traceback:
File "/Volumes/Storage/_codework/testwork/42cc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  204.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Volumes/Storage/_codework/testwork/42cc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:**

How to deal with this string?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do in the view. I assume 'response' is the response from the get_and_save_image function, which in my above example returns a string. '.get' is a method of dictionaries, so it would throw an error.

Comment: If you just want to display the image, simply return the string, i.e. "return HttpResponse(response)"

Comment: Yes! it returns string on template but as far as I understand it is image file byte string. And how to turn it into image itself and then save to model?

Comment: if I manually convert my base64string with http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#  it renders red squire!

Comment: I've tried:

 ` image = Image.frombytes('RGB',(200,200),decodestring(response_string))`

but it gives me an error:
**/PIL/Image.py" in frombytes
 raise ValueError("not enough image data")**
I have Pillow==3.2.0